# Parsing css box shadow string into separate values

Tags: javascript, math, css

You can see in this http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/ box shadow generator angle and distance are calculated into x and y positions for shadow, it's done like this

```
angle = parseInt(angle)*((Math.PI)/180);
x     = Math.round(distance * Math.cos(angle));
y     = Math.round(distance * Math.sin(angle));
```

how would one do the opposite and turn x and y of box shadow css value into a distance and angle?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had a `boxshadow` css value such as `"10px 10px 5px #888888"`

You could split the string on "px" + space with `.split("px ")`

Then you could grab the first 3 values "10" and "10" and "5" which you could convert to integers with `parseInt`

From there you could use those 3 numbers however you want.

Comment: Yes, but the part I have trouble with is calculating angle and distance from those numbers.